# There needs to be a tag(s) for: one-player / single-player

Tags: discussion, tags

Since there are many games that can be played by one person, I feel it would be useful to have a related tag.

Comment: Removed `solitaire` from title since it was pointed out that that could be seen as specifically the card game. Removed `solo` from title since I think that may imply things like playing against a computer.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>No, I think this is a [Meta-Tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/):</strike>

> The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe the content of the question.

We should be careful when tagging using one of those tags. It should only apply when the question is about a game that could be played in solo **and** the question is about that. (a question about [Spider (Solitaire)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_Solitaire) **should not** have that tag).

Comment: there's already a "two-player" tag... hmmm, with only one question... and there's no "multi-player" tag. still seems to me that it's useful to know the difference between 1-, 2- and n-player questions.

Comment: But `solitaire` is not a meta tag; it does talk about the content of the question. If you're asking about solitaire variants of games, then that's what the question is about; it's not a meta-tag. Meta tags are tags that are more about the style of the question, like `subjective` or `beginner`, and that's what the meta tags article is arguing against.

Comment: @Brian Campbell You are right, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want those tags, we need to be consistent with related tags:

- single-player or one-player but not solitair because that can be confusing with the game with the same name.
- dual-player or two-player
- multi-player

Comment: There isn't a game with the name solitaire; there is Klondike solitaire, which is the most popular solitaire card game, and sometimes people refer to it incorrectly as simply solitaire, but on its own, solitaire just means any game you can play by yourself.

Comment: You are probably right, but I still think its confusing.